# Fetching value from array in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to get values from array here is my code

`print_r($new[1]->extra_fields);`
and result is

```
[{"id":"1","value":"compny name"},{"id":"2","value":"Dubai"},    {"id":"3","value":"UAE"},{"id":"4","value":"2014-07-31"},{"id":"5","value":"AED 12000"}]</p>
```

how can i fetch specific values separately like company name ,dubai , AED 12000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have json string in variable

```
foreach(json_decode($new[1]->extra_fields, true) as $field){ // true for assoc value array
   print_r($field);
   print($field['id']);
   print($field['value']);
}
```

Edit: for company name

```
foreach(json_decode($new[1]->extra_fields, true) as $field){ // true for assoc value array
   print_r($field);
   if($field['id'] == "1"){
       $comp_name = $field['value'];break;
   }
}
```

Comment: and what if i only need to get company name ?

Comment: then you need to add check on id like `if ($field['id'] == "1")` because i think in above json  you always have comany name on id 1, 2 .. coutry name, 3..coutry code so on..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it as

```
$extra_fields = json_decode($new[1]->extra_fields); // use json_decode, as value is json encoded
foreach($extra_fields as $field){
   echo $field->value;
}
```